# issue with loading website images

Tags: php, image, caching, browser

Please refer to [this url](http://pluto.promaticstechnologies.com/printeable/explore/collections).

When page loads completely, then:

Then press <kbd>**F5**</kbd> and you can see the images loads again under Collections, and there is white line coming.

It seems that previous image on same place is already fetched from browser cache and same image also fetched from server again which make white lines on old image.

In order to solve the problem, I can do one thing:

I can add a time string with image path like:

```
http://pluto.promaticstechnologies.com/printeable/im.php?f=thing/thing_8_14048155751.jpg&w=310&h=235&t=<current dynamic time>
```

but as there are lot of images in my website in all pages of my websites, so I can't just add this time string quickly on all pages.

I tried to add this string by jquery document ready, but this does not help to solve the issue.

Comment: Show some code so that people can help

Answer (score 0):

1. why you are not use **[htaccess](http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/leverage-browser-caching.html)** file? for image cached problem.
2. Please compress your images. Below are some urls for that

   for **[jpg images](http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/)**

   for **[png images](https://tinypng.com/)**
3. Please Remove unused CSS. [**test your website load**](http://gtmetrix.com/reports/pluto.promaticstechnologies.com/bbbBXlj2). This may be issue.

Comment: I have added htaccess for caching, but still there is issue, because they are not actually images, they are coming from php files. Path of images are like: 
http://pluto.promaticstechnologies.com/printeable/im.php?f=thing/thing_8_14048155751.jpg&w=310&h=235
where f,w and h attributes will change for all images. 
I hope you understand. How i can cache this and how to solve white line problem

Comment: did u store images in database? or only name, height, width?

Comment: I store images in directory, but that is original image only, after that i create images of different size from original image by using php file by passing original image, required width, height etc.
http://pluto.promaticstechnologies.com/printeable/im.php?f=thing/thing_8_14048155751.jpg&w=310&h=235
|

Comment: I checked your website. Please Remove unused CSS. [**test your website load**](http://gtmetrix.com/). This may be issue.